# React not saving ticked checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

components/Settings/index.js

```
    class Settings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activateOption1: true,
      activateOption2: true,
      isPending: false,
      dataPending: false,
      activeData1: false
    };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    const {pet, updatePetStore} = this.props;
    this.setState({activeData1: updatePetStore.petstoreToggles.activeData1});
    this.setState({activateOption1: updatePetStore.petstoreToggles.activateOption1});
  }
  componentUpdate(){
    const {updatePetStores, dispatch, intid } = this.props;
    if(updatePetStore.updatedPetStores == 'pending'){
      if(updatePetStore.updatedNonPetCookie == false){
        if(updatePetStore.selectedToggle == 'isActiveData1' && !this.state.dataPending){
          this.setState({dataPending: true})
        } else if(updatePetStore.selectedToggle == 'ActivateOption1' && !this.state.isPending) {
          this.setState({isPending: true})
        }
      }
    }
    if((updatePetStore.updatedPetCookie && this.state.isPending == true) || (updatePetStore.updatedDataCookie && this.state.dataPending == true)){
      if(this.state.isPending) {
        dispatch(updatedPetCookie(false));
        this.setState({isPending: !this.state.isPending});
        this.setState({ActivateOption1: !this.state.ActivateOption1});
      } else {
        dispatch(updatedDataCookie(false));
        this.setState({dataPending: !this.state.dataPending});
        this.setState({activeData1: !this.state.activeData1});
      }
    }
  }

render () {
    const { petstoreName, pet, updatePetStore } = this.props;
    const petstoreToggles = updatePetSTore.petstoreToggles;
    var petstoreId = petstoreToggles.petstoreId;
    var option2flag;
    {petstoreToggles.ActivateOption1=='Yes' || petstoreToggles.ActivateOption1==true ? option2flag = true : option2flag = false};
    var petChildrenOptions = null;
    var dataChildrenOptions = null;
    if(this.state.ActivateOption1) {
      petChildrenOptions = (
        <div id="options-children">
          <Option
            title="Main"
            modalTitle="Main"
            cookieName="ActivateMain"
            petstore={petstoreName}
            petstoreId={petstoreId}
            active={petstoreToggles.ActivateMain}
          />
          <Option
            title="Option2"
            modalTitle="Option2"
            cookieName="ActivateOption2"
            petstore={petstoreName}
            petstoreId={petstoreId}
            active={option2flag}
          />
          <Option
            title="Option3"
            modalTitle="Option3"
            cookieName="ActivateOption3"
            petstore={petstoreName}
            petstoreId={petstoreId}
            active={true}
          />
          <Option
            title="Option4"
            modalTitle="Option4"
            cookieName="ActivateOption4"
            petstore={petstoreName}
            petstoreId={petstoreId}
            active={petstoreToggles.ActivateOption4}
          />
        </div>
      );
```

components/Settings/Option/index.js

```
const cookie = new Cookies();

class Settings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activate: false,
      activateIsOpen: false,
      update: false
    };
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    const { cookieName, active } = this.props;
    const cookieDomain = getCookieDomain();
    this.setState({activate: active});
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { cookieName, updatePetStore, petstoreId, dispatch } = this.props;
    const updatedpetstores = updatePetStore.updatedpetstores;
    const cookieDomain = getCookieDomain();
    var petstore = null;
    if(updatePetStores.updatedCookieFlag && this.state.update){
      if(cookieName == 'activeOption1' || cookieName == 'ActivateOption1'){
        dispatch(updatedPetCookie(true));
      }
      for(var i = 0 ; i < updatedPetStores.length; i++) {
        {updatedPetStores[i].uuid == petstoresId ? petstore = updatedPetStores[i] : null }
      }
      if (petstore != null) {
        this.state.activate = petstore[cookieName];
        if(petstore.accountId == cookie.get('accountId', {domain: cookieDomain})) {
          cookie.set('ActivateOption1', petstore.ActivateOption1, {path: '/', domain: cookieDomain});
          cookie.set('ActivateOption2', petstore.ActivateOption2, {path: '/', domain: cookieDomain});
          cookie.set('ActivateMain', petstore.ActivateMain, {path: '/', domain: cookieDomain});
          cookie.set('ActivateOption3', petstore.ActivateOption3, {path: '/', domain: cookieDomain});
        }
      }
      dispatch(setCookieUpdateFlag(false));
      this.setState({update: false});
    }
  }

  toggleActivateIsOpen() {
    this.setState({activateIsOpen: !this.state.activateIsOpen});
  }
  yesAction() {
    const { dispatch, cookieName, petstoreId, router } = this.props;
    if(cookieName != 'ActivateOption1' && cookieName != 'activeData1'){
      dispatch(updatedNonPetCookie(true));
    } else {
      dispatch(selectedToggle(cookieName));
      dispatch(updatedNonPetCookie(false));
    }
    dispatch(setActiveCookie(cookieName, petstoreId));
    this.setState({activate: !this.state.activate});
    this.setState({update: true});
    this.toggleActivateIsOpen();
  }
  render () {
    const { title, modalTitle, petstore, dispatch } = this.props;
    const customStyles = {
      content : {
        marginRight           : '-25%',
        transform             : 'translate(-25%, -25%)'
      }
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={this.state.activate == true ? "option-active" : "option"}  onClick={() => this.toggleActivateIsOpen()}>
          {title}
        </div>
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.activateIsOpen}
          shouldCloseOnOverlayClick={true}
          style={customStyles}
          contentLabel="Modal"
        >
          <div className="options-content">
            <div>Are you sure you want to {this.state.isActive == true ? 'deactivate' : 'activate'} {modalTitle} for {petstore}?</div>
            <div className="options-buttons">
              <div className="yes" onClick={() => this.yesAction()}>Yes</div>
              <div className="no" onClick={() => this.toggleActivateIsOpen()}>No</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function select(state) {
  return {
    updatePetStore: state.updatePetStore,
    router: state.router
  }
}

export default connect(select)(Settings);
```

The code rendered will look like this:

```
Option 1 [ ] // checkbox
  Main  [ ]
  Option 2 [ ] 
  Option 3 [ ]
  ...
```

I can check the ticks on the checkbox, but whenever I refresh the checks do not save. How do I solve this issue?

I am guessing this is somehow related with cookies, but how?

Also, whenever I look into the developer console I am seeing an error on this page that is saying "Uncaught Invariant Violation".  I am not sure if this is related, but it might be worth a mention. If I can provide more info, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the state properly, please set the state like this,

```
this.setState({...this.state, activeData1: updatePetStore.petstoreToggles.activeData1});
this.setState({...this.state, activateOption1: updatePetStore.petstoreToggles.activateOption1});
```

you are not mutation the state but overriding it with `activeData1: updatePetStore.petstoreToggles.activeData1`, we need to send new reference to setState everytime need to change the state, contain initial and mutated data, so that it correctly tell React to render.

Example:
suppose we have initial state as

```
this.state = {
      activateOption1: true,
      activateOption2: true,
      isPending: false,
      dataPending: false,
      activeData1: false
    };
```

and now we are setting the state using `setState` api,

```
this.setState({activeData1: updatePetStore.petstoreToggles.activeData1});
this.setState({activateOption1: updatePetStore.petstoreToggles.activateOption1});
```

Now, our state structure becomes like this,

```
this.state = {
  activateOptions1: value //mutated value
}
```

you loose all rest other properties it initially has.

Comment: I get your logic, but I tried that and now the checkboxes don't even show up as checked on the UI when I check them.

Comment: Ok so just with the changes you mentioned:

The checkboxes still work but still don't save upon refresh.

Comment: are u refreshing the page itself or any kind of routing?

Comment: these are local states, it will not survive page refresh, if want it to survive, you have to use localStorage if not using any api's to save it